# AWS ALB: Are Sticky Sessions possible with TCP?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, tcp, sticky-sessions, alb

I need to load-balance my clients. Some of these clients use TCP/TLS, the rest HTTP/HTTPS.

The target services of the load balancer can be in either EC2 instances or ECS containers.

Also, the clients talking TCP need sticky sessions with the target services.

Since the Application Load Balancer expects use of a cookie for allowing sticky sessions and since my TCP client cannot deal with cookies, how do I load-balance both these types of clients in the AWS ecosystem -- without using NGINX Plus?

Comment: For the TCP/TLS clients you may be able to use an NLB (instead of an ALB). However you would need to move the TLS termination to the target system and have the NLB pass through the connection (i.e. No TLS cert on the NLB). This also probably means that you need a different URL/subdomain for the TCP/TLS clients.

Comment: NLB has TLS termination https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-tls-termination-for-network-load-balancers/